# Div Progress bar direction

Tags: html, css, user-interface, progress-bar

I have two progress bars that I've implemented vertically to save some space, however, since html builds things downward the fill for the progress bar is growing downwards instead of up. I was wondering how I could get the progress bar to grow up instead of down? I cannot have the position absolute (a lot of the guides I've looked up recommended that) because the value of the progress bar is a percent which is calculated in the server then sent to the client and set via J Query (.css function). Below is the code for a single progress bar (I have two, one for each team) as well as the picture demonstrating what is happening. 
[Incorrect Orientation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpqjC.png); This is the current code. (I have included the styling in the div). Here is a live version: https://jsfiddle.net/blacy1551/ngn5f5ud/4/

```
T1: <div id="team1Cont" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 15px; 
    height: 200px; ">

   <div id="team1Div" style="background-color: #d9d9d9; width: 15px; height: 
    10%;">
   </div>

</div>
```

Thank you very much I really appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you create a demo? There's very little code in your question for us to help

Answer (score 1):

You can just rotate the div with the progress bar 180 degrees and that should work.

```
#team1Cont {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```